Monthly double email sends in SFMC without affecting sender reputation
I currently send around 200,000 - 250,000 emails per month using SFMC, with a dedicated IP and a good sender reputation. I want to start sending an email to the entire subscriber base, which is around 450,000 active subscribers.
To avoid any risks to the sender reputation, I'm planning to split the send into smaller batches (around 18,000 emails per day) every day for a month (7 days a week). This would result in sending twice as many emails per month as I usually do.
Would this increase in email volume negatively impact the reputation of my sender domain or dedicated IP? Any best practices or recommendations for safely scaling up the send volume in this way?

Normally it is recommended to look at your email volumes week-on-week. Meaning one should not increase the volume in week 2 to more than twice the volume of week 1.
This is why my recommendation will be to increase the volume with max 50%, meaning that given your average week volume is around 55.000, you could do following:

Week 0: 55.000
Week 1: 82.500
Week 2: 124.000
Week 3: 186.000

This will ensure you will reach all 450.000 without experiencing one sudden spike from your regular volume, which would happen if you doubled your volume in one single round.

Why not just send 15k emails per day through 30 days? It will give 450 in total. What is more recommened way to do that?

@teddy23 you are not writing about your sending pattern today. How many emails are you sending per day? Is everything equally distributed, with consistent volumes on a daily basis?

My sending pattern is not constant, I usually send between 3-4k per day to 50k on average. So monthly it gives between 250-300k and weekly between 20-140k.

@teddy23 and this is why I would recommend to increase the volumes steady, as you could multiply your week-on-week volume too much. So in case your week 0 has 20k sends, and you send 15k per day in week 1, you will hit 105k sends. This will for sure trigger some spam alerts out there. I will suggest you to start by adding  50% week-on week, and this is why your daily/weekly volumes are more important than monthly ones.

You wrote "this is why I would recommend to increase the volumes steady, as you could multiply your week-on-week volume too much", but if I send 13k daily through 30 days, the weekly sendout level will be the same - approx 105k through 4 weeks, so there won't be any spikes

And it will be a single occassion, later I won't send that many emails monthly, after this sendout it will go back to approx 250k monthly. I am afraided that gradually increase the sendout for the same email will be trated as another IP warm up
